# Entity Framework update tables relations

Tags: c#, entity

O have  3 tables:

- title (**titleID**, lib)
- chapitres (**chapID**, **titleID**)
- articles (**artID**, **chapID**, **titleid**)

I have a problem on trying to update a title record :

```
 db = new EngDBEntities();

 if (obj != null)
 {
     titresBindingSource.DataSource = obj;
     db.Titres.Attach(titresBindingSource.Current as Titres);
 }
 else
 {
     titresBindingSource.DataSource = new Titres();
     db.Titres.Add(titresBindingSource.Current as Titres);
 }
```

Updating and add new title for add is perfect but for update I get this error :

> Entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Answer (score 0):

Have fun to follow this section of Entity Framework course!

[Updating Related Data with Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: hi sir ... i'm not in asp but in windows form entity f application

Comment: is there some one ... whay when update master table i have this error and when i use :db.Titres.Attach(titresBindingSource.Current as Titres);